# Does TypeScript .9 support the dataset property

Tags: javascript, dataset, typescript

This is with TypeScript 0.9.0.0 in Visual Studio 12 Express. My TypeScriptTarget is set to ES5.

I'm trying to use custom data-* attributes with TypeScript. This is a piece of the html:

```
<button id="b_FillRed" class="Fill" type="button" data-test="Test Data" onclick="canvasFill(this, 'canvas1', 'red')">Fill Red</button>
```

and this is a piece of the TypeScript canvasFill function:

```
var dataTest: string = sender.getAttribute("data-test");
var dataTest1: string = sender.dataset.test;
```

The first line works and dataTest is correctly loaded with "Test Data"
The second line throws an error:
Unable to get property 'test' of undefined or null reference

Am I not doing the correctly or does this just not work?

Comment: The expression-level behavior here doesn't really matter if it was compiled from TypeScript or not. Can you post a self-contained example that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with IE 10. The same file works in both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

IE does not support the `dataset` property. Instead, use `elt.getAttribute("data-test");`. This should change in IE11. See http://caniuse.com/dataset.